# PHP showing closing Image Tag in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I am trying to output an image using the bootstrap 4.0 class  class in wordpress.

Here is the code I have in my loop:

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail('featured-large'); ?>" />
```

here is all of the code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgyNH.png)

On output the images work correctly, but shows the ending "/>" on the page, after the image. As seen here:

[image]

Is there a reason this is happening, or is this code completely wrong?

Comment: if you do `echo` you should use `get_the_post_thumbnail`, because `the_post_thumbnail` already does a display. You probably have some parts twice

Comment: it maybe something else? Try to inspect element and find out if any tags are overlapping?

Comment: actually, more than that: `get_the_post_thumbnail` will display the whole `img` tag too, for the url only, you could use `get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null, 'featured-large')` (edit: not sure if it works with null, it should be post id, maybe you can remove first parameter)

Comment: I don't see any overlapping tags, and I seem to get a larger error with get_the_post_thumbnail, so I can post more code if needed. maybe I have made a greater error?

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing an img tag inside an img tag. Replace your `<img/>` tag with `get_the_post_thumbnail()`, and you can add your class to it like so:

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail(get_the_ID(),'featured-large',array('class'=>'card-img-top');
```

Comment: so, that does work, but causes extra spacing next to my images and functions updates are not showing?

Comment: Can you please post your code as an edit to your question so I can see what's going on? And can you explain what you mean by "functions updates are not showing"?

Comment: Also, if you're wanting responsive images with "srcset" attributes, you're better off using the `get_the_post_thumbnail()` function than just outputting the image url in your own img tag.

Comment: my code is linked at the top. to answer your question, i believe for the bootstrap card options to work the 'img' needs to be included. the images are not properly working with the bootstrap functionality

Comment: The class "card-img-top" is what triggers Bootstrap. If you replace the entirety of line 36 (based on your linked code image) with the code I gave you, surrounded with `<?php ?>` of course, it will output your img tag with the proper class.

Answer (score 0):

the function you are using is display image, if you want to get the url just use this to fetch url of image and then put it into the img tag

```html
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );

<img src="<?php echo $image[0];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
```